# jenkins environment injector plugin error

Tags: variables, jenkins, plugins

i use global variables in jenkins to set build and deploy configuration.

but i want to restrict this variables at only dedicated job.
someone said the Envinjector plugin could do it. so i installed it but i can not find the build configuration like the image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7laDT.png)

i use jenkins 2.277.4 version and Envinjector 2.4.0 version
and my job is multibranch pipeline job

below image is my job image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0eoB.png)